# Changing easing parameters

Tags: three.js, tween, easing, period, amplitude

I have a tweening function to animate the camera angle using "Easing.Elastic.Out".  How do I change the Period and Amplitude of the easing?

```js
camera.lookAt(scene);
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

function camTweenLeft (startAngle){
   var prevAngle=startAngle;
   var tween = new TWEEN.Tween({angle:startAngle})
   .to({angle:startAngle - 40*Math.PI/180},1000)
  .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.Out)
  .onUpdate(function(){
   controls.rotateLeft(this.angle-prevAngle);
   prevAngle=this.angle;
  })
  .start()
  }
```

Comment: unless you write your own `easing` function you cannot change the attributes you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check the TWEEN JS documentation as its a library used by Three.js but not part of it.

https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md

The graphs example shows what easing functions you can have at https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/examples/03_graphs.html

You can also create your own custom easing function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think TweenJS exposes `period` and `amplitude` to be changed for an `Elastic` ease but [GSAP](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Elastic/) does ;) i.e. only if you are interested in giving it a try.